# mongodb : how to get documents that contains nested field

Tags: mongodb

How can i get documents that contains nested field f5=12?

> db.products.insert( { f: "card", f1: {f2 : {f3 : 15 } } } )
>
> db.products.insert( { f: "card", f1: {f2 : {f4 : {f5 : 12} } } } )
>
> db.products.insert( { f: "card", f1: {f2 : {f3 : {f5 : 43} } } } )
>
> db.products.insert( { f: "card", f1: {f2 : {f4 : 98 } } } )

I've tried smth like this:

> db.products.find($where : "this.content.indexOf('f5 : 12') != -1")
>
> db.products.find( {$elemMatch : {f5 : 12} })

But it doesn't work..
Does anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot notation in your query to do this:

```js
db.products.find({'f1.f2.f4.f5': 12})
```

If you want something more flexible where you don't have to specify each of the parent keys, you'd need to search the docs using a [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#_S_where) operator.